# Copy HTML Table to localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a table that is being generated automatically through the javascript application.

See test site here:  https://hhpricetools.com/3d-wood-designer/

The summary table is on the last tab or you can click "view summary" at the top to get to it.

The table that is populated based on user choices looks like this:

```
<table id="summary-table" class="hhpt-summarytable"><tbody>
<tr><td>Style:  <b>Side Lofted Barn</b></td>
<td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Size:  <b>10' x 16'</b></td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Siding:  <b>LP Smartside - Painted</b></td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Wall Color:  <b>Quest Gray #7080</b></td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Trim Color:  <b>White</b></td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Roof:  <b>Radiant Barrier LP Techshield</b></td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

That I am wanting to save to localStorage.  For some reason I am getting "undefined" on the actual website above.  The jsfiddle works fine, though.  Why isn't it doing the same on the website?

```
var table_copy = $('#summary-table').html();
    localStorage.setItem('table',table_copy);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("table"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebryjz1q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods that you can do to make sure that your JavaScript loads after the DOM/HTML loads.

---

**1. Use `defer`**

You can use `defer` to load the JavaScript after the HTML has loaded.

To do this, you can simply add the following attribute.

```html
<script defer src="index.js"></script>
```

This should wait until the DOM has loaded before actually loading the JavaScript.

---

**2. Add `<script>` to `<body>`**

Another solution is to add the `script` tag to the end of the `body`. This will make the JavaScript code load after all of the HTML has loaded.

---

**3. Wait in JavaScript**

You can also wait for the DOM to load in JavaScript (without JQuery).

There are two methods.

1. You can use the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener. This will wait until the HTML has loaded. However, it won't wait for the images to load, stylesheets, etc.

   To use this, you can use `addEventListener()`.

   ```js
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     // Code here will execute only after the DOM has loaded...
   });
   ```
2. You can also use the `load` event, which will load after the HTML has loaded, as well as images, stylesheets, etc.

   You can use this listener with `addEventListener` too.

   ```js
   window.addEventListener("load", () => {
     // Code here will execute after everything has loaded...
   });
   ```

   You can do the same thing with the `onload` event handler property.

   ```js
   window.onload = () => {
     // Code here will execute after everything has loaded...
   };
   ```

---

In conclusion, there are many ways to make the JavaScript wait until the DOM has loaded.

Comment: I tried that too.... <script defer src="https://hhpricetools.com/wood/test.js"></script> and it's still undefined.

Comment: See my edit. It has a few more solutions that you can try.

Comment: Thank you Arnav!  The onload event handler worked like a charm when all the others didn't.  Now I'm having an issue with it not updating when user changes options.  It captures only the default options in localStorage now.  So how do I update the localStorage on change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the DOM has fully loaded before trying to store the HTML.

Try the following:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var table_copy = $('#summary-table').html();
    localStorage.setItem('table',table_copy);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("table"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, i just did as you instructed and it's still "undefined" :(

Comment: Seems to be working for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/m5w1ejvu/

Comment: Yeah I know, works on jsfiddle just not on my website :/

Comment: Not sure where you're placing your JS, but it's not getting wrapped inside the $('document').ready: https://snipboard.io/P6wVBO.jpg